# show one of values of combobox when the form loaded

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox and i add some value to it:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        comboBox_Status.Items.Add("All");
        comboBox_Status.Items.Add("Available");
        comboBox_Status.Items.Add("not Available");

        comboBox_Status.SelectedIndex = 0;

        ShowUserInfo(SearchString);
    }
```

then, i want to show "All" for default when form will load. 
i use this:
 comboBox_Status.SelectedIndex = 0;
but it doesn't work. please help if anyone know how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a List of the string you intend to feed the combobox.

```
var strings = List<string>(){"All", "Available", "Not Available"};
```

Then feed it to your comboBox using the "combobox.itemSource"

```
comboBox.ItemsSource = strings;
```

Finally, set the first item to be selected as

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

comboBox.SelectedItem = "All";